# Convert regex.findall into a new list

Tags: python, regex, list, ubuntu

I am trying to write a script that will display everything in a directory then use the the check output results to locate the file to convert it.

For example running the command `ls -ltr ./*` in `/home/python` will display everything.

If I have a file inside `/home/python/test` it will give me the results. Now I am trying to use `check_output` and use the `locate` command to display the path in order to use another command to convert the file into another format.

This is what I have so far:

```
import sys    
import subprocess
from glob import glob

def main():
    grep_month = " | grep $(date '+%b')"

    output = subprocess.check_output(["ls -ltr ./*" + "".join([str(i) for i in grep_month])], shell=True)

    my_list = output.split()
    for element in my_list:
        m = re.findall('(.*text.*)', element)
        print m

if __name__ == "__main__"
    main()
```

Python goes through each element and finds any files in txt but it prints `[]` for none found, I only want a list with those found in order to convert the files into another format I want to integrate locate command in ubuntu so I can find the path then write more code in order to convert the file, which I need to specify the path. Make sense?

This gives me a list of all the files with the current month.

Now I want to strip the list of elements to do a locate on all the files only.

Comment: the `*` token matches 0 or more of whatever token is before it. change your pattern to be more specific in what you are matching

Comment: K, changed and used just txt. Print results in  [] [] [] [] [] ['./file.txt] [] [] [] each in new line. How do I get rid of the []? Also convert the result of ['file.txt'] into a list to use as a variable later? Sorry new to python still reading and learning.

Comment: initialize an empty list outside of your `for element in my_list` loop then do an empty list check before appending m to the list. something if `if m: filelist.append(m)`

Comment: awesome that worked thanks.